# Entity-Framework : Delay on first access when having one database per tenant in multi-tenancy app

Tags: entity-framework, web-applications, multi-tenant

We have a multi-tenant asp.net web application that is available on Azure. Each tenant has its own database. For cutting in hosting costs, a database can be put offline and put back online when a request for that tenant is made.

The problem is that the first access on that database is extremely slow, leading to many timeouts. What I find hard to understand is how is this an issue because the database schema, and by that the EF mappings, are the same for all databases.
Is there anything that can be made to solve this?

(Note: were using EF 6.1.3; SQL Azure and Elastic pool for the databases)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: "a database can be put offline and put back online when a request for that tenant is made"?

Comment: Our databases are in a Azure elastic pool. What we notice is that some database is not used for some time, some background process put this DB in what seems to be a offline state. When data from this DB is requested, it is putted back online. But the first access to the data is very very slow.